# Чёрно-белая карта

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, яндекс-карты

Всем привет! Подскажите плз в чём может быть проблема, локально карта цветная, на стенде чёрно-белая. В кратце стенд тоже используют яндекс карту только со своими настройками
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так может проблема в «только со своими настройками»?

Comment: Копайте в сторону CSS-фильтров.